# How to use PHP to send data over to another page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a website which is supposed to show some information about food courts from MySQL server and what I have done is that I made it such that the data would be shown in the website and if they click they would be redirected to another web page. My question is how would I be able to check what is the hyperlink they clicked so that I could display accurate information on the second webpage?

What I have done is that I tried to use get to send the information over but to no avail. Can someone guide me please? I am new to PHP and MySQL coding.

This is the PHP code for the website that I am using to display the food court information.

```
              <?php
    require 'dbFunction.php';
    $con = getDbConnect();
    if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM foodcourt");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<a href=\"foodstalldetail.php?fc=$row[FCNo]\">Foodcourt " . $row['FCNo'] . "</a><br />";
        echo $row['FCDescription'] . "<br />";
        echo $row['FCImage'] . "<br />";
        echo "<br>";
        $data=$row['FCNo'];
        } 
    } else {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

And this is the code I use to "receive" the information.

```
    <?php
    require 'dbFunction.php';
    $con = getDbConnect();
    $data = $_GET['$row[FCNo]'];
    if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                   $result = mysqli_query($con,
                "SELECT * "
                . "FROM StallDetails SD AND FoodDetails FD"
                . "WHERE FD.StallID = SD.StallID "
                . "AND FD.FCNo = ".$data);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "Foodcourt " . $row['FCNo'] . "<br />";
            echo $row['Details']."<br />";
            echo $row['Description'].",<br> ";
            echo "Price: $".$row['Price']."<br> ";
    }  }
    else {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
```

This is my getDbConnect();

```
    <?php
    function getDbConnect() {
    // get a database connect to studentacad database
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "waduser01", "password123", "p1315774");
    Return $con;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Your code is fundamentally broken and vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Security issues isn't a problem because I am actually doing this for a school project. I am using this purely for academic purposes and not for commercial usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Your are using $row in get variable too and You are also not enclosing the $data in quotes `''`.And one more thing you are not selecting the database. Use `mysqli_select_db` function to select your database.You are also using AND in selecting the table. use the code below

```
  <?php
        require 'dbFunction.php';
        $con = getDbConnect();
mysqli_select_db($con,"db_name");
        $data = $_GET['fc'];
        if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                       $result = mysqli_query($con,
                    "SELECT * "
                    . "FROM StallDetails SD , FoodDetails FD"
                    . "WHERE FD.StallID = SD.StallID "
                    . "AND FD.FCNo = '".$data."'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con,$result)) {
                echo "Foodcourt " . $row['FCNo'] . "<br />";
                echo $row['Details']."<br />";
                echo $row['Description'].",<br> ";
                echo "Price: $".$row['Price']."<br> ";
        }  }
        else {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I used the code and I am receiving an warning.        Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\CA2\foodStallDetail.php on line 31

Comment: I have edited my answer please check it. I hope this will work for you

Comment: The same error is appearing despite using the updated code you have shared with me.

Comment: Sorry Another edit it may solve your problem

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con,$result)) { is the line with the error. It doesn't stop appearing despite using your updated code.

Comment: Are you selecting the database in dbFunctions.php

Comment: dbFunctions.php is only used to connect to the MySQL database.

Comment: Can you please provide my your dbFunction.php

Comment: Hi, I realised the error might have been that I tried to pull data out from 2 MySQL tables. Is there a chance that it is my table that has the error?

Comment: Hi, I included dbFunction.php in the question above. Thanks

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You have not selected your database. Hope this will now solve your problem

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem. It is that there is a syntax error with the SQL in the str. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send any data.

Usually, GET variables are used. Example:

```
<a href="user.php?id=344">Wayne</a>
```

Would lead to a file called user.php, in which the GET variable `id` is checked:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : false;
```

In this example, once you have the `id`, you can decide on what user details to display:

```
$userDetails = $user->get($id);
```

Another example:

```
<a href="details.php?show=recipe&id=34">Wayne</a>
```

... translates into:

- show=recipe
- id=34

Comment: Wow, thanks for the advise. I would try it out and if I encounter future problems, I would comment it here. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I would just like to ask, would this work the same way for MySQL? I understand what you meant but I do not know if it is possible to use MySQL to replace $userDetails?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing your variable like this: 
    $_GET['$row[FCNo]'];

But it looks like the variable in the url is fc, so you would access it like this:
    $_GET['fc'];

Comment: Hi, I edited it like that but it doesn't work due to an error that says mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\CA2\foodStallDetail.php